# Log4j CVE-2021-44228 affect on the dependent libraries

Tags: security, log4j2

As most of the IT folks know this vulnerability, I have a question on the affect it would have on the system that uses the libraries using log4j affected versions.

So let's say my app (APP_1) is dependent on dependency1.war. This dependency1.war is using say log4j 2.8.x version which is affected with the vulnerability mentioned.

How would this have an affect on the system APP_1 is deployed on and application itself (App_1)?
What would be a recommended way to safeguard against attacks?

Much thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that your app is at one point logging a value that is coming from a user, say a request parameter value. (This in itself is a bad programming practice but very common). If the user sends a request where this parameter is a specially crafted string then, because of this vulnerability, log4j would allow execution of another program on the host machine, for example